# XPath translate() within contains() with dynamic variable

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working in VBscript with an application that has XPath to return matching node information.

To make it case insensitive I am using translate function. There is a variable that holds value to search for (say v_Search). After I implemented `translate()` it is not returning matching nodes rather it returns all nodes in XML.

Below XPath returns correct information but is case sensitive ;-

```
//*[contains(., '"& v_search &"')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

To make it case insensitive I implemented `translate()` but it is not able to check for matching result. Below is expression :-

```
//*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') , v_search)]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong..

> 1. This expression returns everything from xml document.
> 2. I have already tried `'"& v_search &"'` in that case it does not give any result.

**Edit** After figuring out problem

```
//*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), translate('"& v_search &"', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

Still it doesn't returns only matching nodes. However it doesn't return entire xml node now.

**Edit:-** Sample Xml

```
<root xmlns="https://jlkjsdlfjl/">
    <name>Accounts</name>
    <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
    <locales>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>de</locale>
    </locales>
    <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
    <searchspace>
        <name locale="en">Accounts</name>
        <name locale="de">Accounts</name>
        <lastChanged>2014-03-05T18:47:30</lastChanged>
        <lastChangedBy>userx</lastChangedBy>
        <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
        <searchspace>
            <name locale="en">Database L</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database L</name>
            <searchSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">SName1</name>
                <name locale="zw">qskxyz</name>
                <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName1</name>
                    <name locale="zw">qixyz</name>
                    <hello>v_search</hello>
                </searchItem>
                 <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName2</name>
                    <name locale="zw">abc</name>
                    v_search
                </searchItem>
                 <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName3</name>
                    <name locale="zw">def</name>
                    <hello>something else</hello>
                </searchItem>
            </searchSubject>
        </searchspace>
    </searchspace>
    <searchspace>
        <name locale="en">Names</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
        <searchspace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
            <searchSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">SName2</name>
                <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName4</name>
                    <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                </searchItem>
            </searchSubject>
        </searchspace>
    </searchspace>
</root>
```

Sample result:

> Accounts,   Database L,  SName1,  IName 1
>
> --------,   ----------, -------,  IName 2

These two hirarchy contains the v_search text.... Others should not come.

Comment: After you added translate, I don't understand why you do "//" right before "ancestor-or-self". This will get you all children complying a condition and the ancestors of each one.

Comment: That was a mistake...... still it has issue.. I am editing the question.

Comment: In your xml there are no home nodes but the xpath is looking for them in the filter. (local-name()='home')

Comment: Sorry I just replaced "home" node with 'name'

Comment: You have made so many little corrections in the course of this thread that it's probably best to start again with a new question. Make the problem reproducible, so anyone can take your code and your data and see if they get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), translate('v_search', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]/ancestor-or-self::*/name[@locale='en']
```

I have tested it in xpathtester and result is:

```
<name locale="en">Accounts</name>
<name locale="en">Database L</name>
<name locale="en">SName1</name>
<name locale="en">IName1</name>
<name locale="en">IName2</name>
```

Comment: Thank you @derloopkat, it was the same as in my question but I was missing in testing it.

Answer (score 1):

`contains(.... , v_search)` is indeed wrong. The expression compares the first argument with value of a child element `v_search`. It always return true in case `v_search` element is not found in current context element, or if the element is found but contains empty string.

Since you're turning the first argument of `contains()` to lower-case, you need to make sure that `v_search` variable is also containing lower-case string.

Comment: I have edited after that change, The result is still not correct however  it doesn't returns whole xml nodes now please suggest......

Comment: It isn't clear where's the problem now without being able to see your XML and compare it to your XPath.

Comment: If you could post a sample keyword to replace the variable `v_search` and a very simplified XML just enough to demonstrate what should be selected and what is being selected insead, it will be far easier to help.

Comment: Btw, you could test your XPath against an XML independently from VBA in an XPath tester like for example http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath (or any other xpath tester really)